# Explaining score KIE Workbench

Tags: drools, optaplanner, kie-workbench

How I can get score explanation in KIE Workbench?

I found this code in docs but where I need to put it? I have only drl files and solver configuration xml

```
for (ConstraintMatchTotal constraintMatchTotal : guiScoreDirector.getConstraintMatchTotals()) {
   String constraintName = constraintMatchTotal.getConstraintName();
// The score impact of that constraint
   Score scoreTotal = constraintMatchTotal.getScoreTotal();

   for (ConstraintMatch constraintMatch : constraintMatchTotal.getConstraintMatchSet()) {
     List<Object> justificationList = constraintMatch.getJustificationList();
     Score score = constraintMatch.getScore();
     ...
     }
}
```

Is here a  way to break down score by constraints?

Comment: See the section above it on how you attain the guiScoreDirector

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet but question is same - where this code should to be placed?

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet is there a way to execute this java code after finding best solution in KIE Workbench or this feature is available only using java-package optaplanner version?

Comment: only available from java engine right now indeed